# EEG Band Extraction

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, signal-processing, mne-python, eeglab

I performed band extraction on my EEG dataset and got the following results:

Power Spectral Density for Alpha band:

[image: Power Spectral Density for Alpha band]

PSD for Beta Band:

[image: PSD for Beta Band]

PSD for Delta Band:

[image: PSD for Delta Band]

The plot shows Frequency(Hz) on X-axis and Power/Frequency(dB/Hz) on Y-axis. The values on Y-axis are negative. What does that indicate? How can I plot for a particular channel P3 with respect to time(sec)?

Code:

```
import numpy as np

freq_bands = {
    'delta': (0.5, 4),
    'theta': (4, 8),
    'alpha': (8, 13),
    'beta': (13, 30),
    'gamma': (30, 40)  
}

band_data = {}

# Iterate through each frequency band and extract the corresponding data
for band_name, (low_freq, high_freq) in freq_bands.items():
    # Apply bandpass filter
    raw_band = raw.copy().filter(l_freq=low_freq, h_freq=high_freq, fir_design='firwin')

    # Append the band data to the dictionary
    band_data[band_name] = raw_band

    delta_data = band_data['delta']
    theta_data = band_data['theta']
    alpha_data = band_data['alpha']
    beta_data = band_data['beta']
    gamma_data = band_data['gamma']
```

Code to plot the extracted bands:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Plot the PSD for each frequency band
for band_name, band_raw in band_data.items():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    band_raw.plot_psd(fmin=freq_bands[band_name][0], fmax=freq_bands[band_name][1], ax=ax,   show=False)
    ax.set_title(f'Power Spectral Density - {band_name.capitalize()} Band')
    ax.set_xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Power/Frequency (dB/Hz)')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: The y axis is power/Hz on a log scale so that 0dB = whatever the reference power is for EEG signals. +10dB is 10x more, -10dB is 10x less (or it could be +20dB/-20dB depending on the convention used for power in EEG). The graphs have a confusing number of coloured lines on - not an MRE. Also the cutoff for the alpha band appears too low at 14Hz since the lhs of the beta band looks to have  alpha signal up to 16Hz might be better.